# Equivalence of the existence of some ultrafilter and some elementary embedding

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

I'm in the proof of showing, that the consistency of 2-huge cardinals implies the consistency of hyper-huge cardinals and it needs this equivalence:

Let $\kappa,\kappa',\lambda,\lambda'$ be cardinals. I want to show the equivalence of the existence of a normal ultrafilter U on $\mathcal{P(\lambda')}$ with $\{ x\subseteq\lambda'\vert x \cap\kappa\in\kappa,\text{otp}(x\cap\kappa')=\kappa, \text{otp}(x)=\lambda\}\in U$ and the existence of an elementary embedding $j\colon V \to M$ for some M with:

(1) $crit(j)=\kappa$

(2) $\lambda<j(\kappa)=\kappa'$

(3) $\lambda'=j(\lambda)$

(4) $^{\lambda'}M \subseteq M$

So far i have shown the existence of the ultrafilter if there is such an embedding. But for the other direction i wanted to ask, if it's the right way to just build the ultrapower like in the normal equivalence with measurable cardinals but with $\mathcal{P(\lambda')}$ as an index? If not, could maybe someone give me a hint on what to do?

Edit: I think now i can show everything but $\lambda < j(\kappa)$. I don't see why this should be true. It seems to me, that the ultrafilter gives no correspondence of $\kappa$ and $\lambda$. Does anybody have a hint for me, why this should be true?

Edit 2: I could change the set, which need to be in the ultrafilter to
$\{ x\subseteq\lambda'\vert x \cap\kappa\in\kappa,\text{otp}(x\cap\kappa')=\kappa, \text{otp}(x)=\lambda, \text{otp}(x \cap \lambda)<\kappa\}$ and because the new condition is equivalent to $\lambda <j(\kappa)$ it would be in $U$ if you assume such an embedding.
But is it necessary to add this?

Comment: Do you know the standard proof that supercompactness can be characterized by closed embeddings and by fine and normal ultrafilters?

Comment: Unfortunately not. i don't even know what closed embeddings are in this context or what fine ultrafilters are. Is the proof very similar to the proof i want to do?

Comment: If you want to learn about large cardinals, supercompactness is a key property that you should probably learn. Closed embeddings mean that the target model ($M$ in that case) is relatively closed under sequences (in this case $j(\lambda)$-sequences). Perhaps looking for the standard proof about huge cardinals and ultrafilters would suffice, but I strongly recommend learning about supercompactness.

Comment: See http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1984-090-04/S0002-9939-1984-0733411-6/S0002-9939-1984-0733411-6.pdf for the huge cardinals characterization with ultrafilters.

Comment: Thanks for the help. i will see through this and maybe come back if i have still problems with this. I will also look into supercompact cardinals because i already noticed that they come up everywhere even in this proof im going through right now.

Comment: Are you reading Usuba's work on the DDG?

Comment: Yes, i want to write my master thesis about it.

Comment: Who's your advisor?

Comment: Prof. Ralf Schindler

Comment: Well, Münster is fun. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! I like it here, too.

Comment: So, with the link you gave me and some other literature i could figure out everything but $\lambda < j(\kappa)$, because i don't see, how there is any correlation between the both. Can you give me a hint, why this should be true?